# Resolving class name to type accelerator name

Tags: powershell

I have somewhat by accident discovered how to consistently get the type accelerator name (ie, a short name) for a class by using `"$(...)"`, eg:

```
PS H:\> "$([System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher])"
adsisearcher
PS H:\> "$([adsisearcher])"
adsisearcher
PS H:\> "$([type]'System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher')"
adsisearcher
PS H:\> "$([type]'adsisearcher')"
adsisearcher
```

Or if you have an instance of the class:

```
PS H:\> "$(([System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]'').GetType())"
adsisearcher
PS H:\> "$(([adsisearcher]'').GetType())"
adsisearcher
```

But looking at the properties of that class (eg `[System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher] | fl`) I can't actually see "adsisearcher" anywhere in there. Calling `ToString()` doesn't help either, as you get the full class name:

```
PS H:\> [System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher].ToString()
System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
PS H:\> [adsisearcher].ToString()
System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
```

Can anyone explain how this `"$(...)"` is actually able to resolve the short name? Where is the "return value" coming from?

There are many other answers on SO that explain how to get the full list of type accelerators, but I couldn't find any that explain this `"$(...)"` behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the `$()` operation that does it, it's the conversion from `[type]` to `[string]`:

```
PS H:\> [System.Int32] -as [string]
int
```

For code generation use cases, type name translation is also exposed via the `LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTypeNameToPSTypeName()` static method, which produces a valid type literal token given the name of a resolvable type:

```
PS H:\> [System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTypeNameToPSTypeName('System.Int32')
[int]
PS H:\> [System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTypeNameToPSTypeName('System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher')
[adsisearcher]
```

> But looking at the properties of that class (eg `[System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher] | fl`) I can't actually see "adsisearcher" anywhere in there.

That's because type accelerators are type name aliases imposed by PowerShell *on top of* the underlying (.NET) type system - the target types themselves have no clue whatsoever about what a "type accelerator" is.

The true "origin" of the builtin type accelrator names are [hardcoded lists of type mappings in PowerShell's language engine](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/76cef3b299911ba264fef7a2f510dd633f36497d/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/TypeResolver.cs#L809)

Comment: Ok, that's very helpful, thanks! One follow-up, if I may: why is there a difference between ````[System.Int32] -as [string]```` (which seems to produce the same results as ````[string][System.Int32]````) and ````[System.Int32].ToString()````? iow, what method is being called to perform the conversion?

Comment: @fission `[System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTo([System.Int32], [string])`. In other words, PowerShell has it's own type conversion layer to make things like type coercion during parameter binding and implicit formatting work smoothly, and calling `ToString()` is just a _fallback_ during conversion to `[string]`

Comment: Ah thanks. That's also the reason why collections/arrays, like  from `Get-ChildItem C:\,` get represented as a concatenated list of names when casted to String.
It seems it uses `[System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTo($fsItems,[string])`

Comment: It's more like `$fsItems.ForEach({[LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTo($_,[string])}) -join $(if($null -ne $OFS){$OFS}else{' '})`, but yeah :)

Comment: Got it… great explanation, thanks! I'll read the [````TypeResolver.cs````](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/TypeResolver.cs) and [````LanguagePrimitives.cs````](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs) files, too.